# Momoko, Jinja2 and Tornado

Tags: postgresql, tornado, jinja2, momoko

there is something fundamentally wrong with my code. These are my
tornado handlers with basic authentication and jinja2 as template
engine. The following works without the momoko db parts.

```
class BaseHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    @property
    def db(self):
        return self.application.db   
    def get_current_user(self):
        return self.get_secure_cookie("user")

class TemplateHandler(BaseHandler):
    """Request handler for writing HTML templates."""
    def render(self, template_name, **kwargs):
        """Renders a Jinja2 template."""
        kwargs['options'] = options.as_dict()
        template = templates.environment.get_template(template_name)
        html = template.render(kwargs)
        self.write(html)

class AuthLoginHandler(TemplateHandler):
    def get(self):
        try:
            errormessage = self.get_argument("error")
        except:
            errormessage = ""
        self.render("login.html", errormessage = errormessage)

    def check_permission(self, password, username):
        if username == "admin" and password == "admin":
            return True
        return False

    def post(self):
        username = self.get_argument("username", "")
        password = self.get_argument("password", "")
        auth = self.check_permission(password, username)
        if auth:
            self.set_current_user(username)
            self.redirect(self.get_argument("next", u"/"))
        else:
            error_msg = u"?error=" + tornado.escape.url_escape("Login incorrect")
            self.redirect(u"/auth/login/" + error_msg)

    def set_current_user(self, user):
        if user:
            self.set_secure_cookie("user", tornado.escape.json_encode(user))
        else:
            self.clear_cookie("user")

class AuthLogoutHandler(TemplateHandler):
    def get(self):
       self.clear_cookie("user")
       self.redirect(self.get_argument("next", "/"))


class MainHandler(TemplateHandler):
    @gen.engine
    def get(self):
        username = tornado.escape.xhtml_escape(self.current_user)
        try:
            cursor = yield momoko.Op(self.db.execute, 'SELECT * FROM products;')
        except Exception as error:
            self.write(str(error))
        res = 'Query results: '+''.join(str(cursor.fetchall()))
        self.render("index.html", username = username, cip = self.request.remote_ip, res = res)
```

For the logged in client, this code should execute a basic query and then print the result to the defined location ( {{ res }} ) within the jinja template. When I try to start the server, I get this:

line 22, in render
        kwargs['options'] = options.as_dict()
    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'as_dict'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We'll need to see your "import" statements to know what's wrong for certain. I suspect you have:

```
from tornado import options
```

But you need:

```
from tornado.options import options
```

Comment: thank you! Exactly as you suspected. The new imports

`import json
import tornado.web
from tornado import gen
from tornado.options import options
from app import templates

import momoko
import psycopg2
`   
now it says    

line 25, in render
        self.write(html)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado-4.0.2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/tornado/web.py", line 652, in write
        raise RuntimeError("Cannot write() after finish().  May be caused "
    RuntimeError: Cannot write() after finish().  May be caused by using async operations without the @asynchronous decorator.

Comment: gen.coroutine instead of gen.engine  |  now it's running. Once again thanks for the help!

Comment: Ah, I didn't catch that bug. gen.coroutine is, essentially, a *combination* of gen.engine and "asynchronous". But gen.engine is obsolete, use gen.coroutine from now on.